# Need help in creating a new array out of existing array

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this:

```
const foo = [{
        cur: "GBT",
        val: [800, 450]
    },
    {
        cur: "USD",
        val: 100
    },
    {
        cur: "EUR",
        val: 200
    },
    {
        cur: "GBT",
        val: [100, 250]
    }]
```

I want to achieve below structure out of above array:

```
   [{
        id: 0,
        cur: "GBT",
        val: 800
    },

    {
        id: 1,
        cur: "GBT",
        val: 450
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        cur: "USD",
        val: 100
    },

    {
        id: 3,
        cur: "EUR",
        val: 200
    },

    {
        id: 4,
        cur: "GBT",
        val: 100
    },

    {
        id: 5,
        cur: "GBT",
        val: 250
    }]
```

This is what i tried:

```
foo.reduce((x, y, i, a) => {
    let resObj = {};
    if (Array.isArray(y.val)) {
        let cnt = 0;
        (a.indexOf(y) === 0 ? cnt : cnt += i)
        for (let j = 0; j < y.val.length; j++) {
            const obj = {};
            obj["id"] = cnt;
            obj["value"] = y.val[j]
            obj["currency"] = y.cur;
            x.push(obj);
            cnt++;
        }
    } else {
        let cnt = 1
        resObj["id"] = i + cnt;
        resObj["value"] = y.val;
        resObj["currency"] = y.cur;
    }
    return x.concat(resObj)
}, [])
```

> Bugs Observed
>   1. When reduce function finds the next val of the object which is of type array, it is not increasing the counter, so the id is equal to the previous counter.
>   2. I also want to know how can i avoid creating blank object if the object has val which is an array, not sure what is the actual reason for this to happen. 
>   Please find the result attachment
>   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlG35.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Array.prototype.reduce()` might help you. `reduce()` callback takes two arguments, who's first argument is the old/previous iteration value and second argument is the current iteration value/element.

So using this function we can holds our current iteration values to the previous iteration value (total values).

> The [**reduce()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method executes a reducer function (that you provide) on each element of the array, resulting in a single output value.

```js
const foo = [{cur: "GBT",val: [800, 450]},{cur: "USD",val: 100},{cur: "EUR",val: 200},{cur: "GBT",val: [100, 250]}]

const result = foo.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    if (Array.isArray(cur.val)) {
        cur.val.map(val => !!(acc.push({id: acc.length, cur: cur.cur, val: val})))
    } else {
        acc.push({id: acc.length, cur: cur.cur, val: cur.val})
    }
     return acc
}, [])
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested `flatMap()` and nested `map()` if the `val` prop is an array. After getting 1D array use `map()` to insert `id` property.

```js
const foo = [{
        cur: "GBT",
        val: [800, 450]
    },
    {
        cur: "USD",
        val: 100
    },
    {
        cur: "EUR",
        val: 200
    },
    {
        cur: "GBT",
        val: [100, 250]
    }]
const res = foo.flatMap(x => Array.isArray(x.val) ? 
                           x.val.map(val => ({cur: x.cur, val})) :
                           {...x}
                   ).map((x,id) => ({...x, id}))
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce the array by taking the value as array, too.

```js
var data = [{ cur: "GBT", val: [800, 450] }, { cur: "USD", val: 100 }, { cur: "EUR", val: 200 }, { cur: "GBT", val: [100, 250] }],
    id = 0,
    result = data.reduce((r, { cur, val }) => {
        [].concat(val).forEach(val => {
            r.push({ id, cur, val });
            id++;
        });
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're resetting value of count in every iteration, you can take it out of reduce,

```js
const foo = [{ cur: "GBT", val: [800, 450] }, { cur: "USD", val: 100 }, { cur: "EUR", val: 200 }, { cur: "GBT", val: [100, 250] }]
let cnt = 0;
let op = foo.reduce((x, y, i, a) => {
    if (Array.isArray(y.val)) {
      for (let j = 0; j < y.val.length; j++) {
        x.push({id:cnt,value:y.val[j], currency: y.cur});
        cnt++;
      }
    } else {
        x.push({id:cnt,value:y.val, currency: y.cur});
        cnt++
    }
    return x
}, [])

console.log(op)
```

Or you can simply use reduce and forEach

```js
const foo = [{ cur: "GBT", val: [800, 450] }, { cur: "USD", val: 100 }, { cur: "EUR", val: 200 }, { cur: "GBT", val: [100, 250] }]
let count = 0

let op = foo.reduce((op, { cur, val }) => {
  if (Array.isArray(val)) {
    val.forEach(value => {
      op.push({ cur, id: count, val: value })
      count++
    })
  } else {
    op.push({ cur,id: count, val})
    count++
  }
  return op
}, [])

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either do this the easy way, which won't be very efficient but also won't matter even slightly unless you're processing arrays with hundreds of entries, or you can do this the efficient way and you'll have to work with several data structures.

The easy way:

1. use map and return *arrays* so that `{ cur: "GBT", val: [800, 450] }` becomes `[{ cur: "GBT", val: 800 }, { cur: "GBT", val: 450}]`.
2. `flat()`-en the result so that `[ [{...},{...}], {...}, [{...}, {...}]`  becomes `[{...}, {...}, {...}, {...}, {...}]`.
3. use one more map to add incremental `id` properties.

And because `.flatMap` exists we can turn steps 1 and 2 into a single step.

So, in code:

```
function mapFn(e) {
  if (!e.v.map) return e;
  return e.v.map(val => ({cur: e.cur, val}));
};

function convertData(input) {
  return array.flatMap(mapFn).map((e,id) => {
    e.id = id;
    return e;
  });
}
```

Nice and simple, but two maps is less efficient than a single pass. So, if we wanted to avoid that:

1. start with an empty target array, and an entry adding function that takes care of the `id` administration, and
2. then iterate through your original array and expand-and-process each entry individually.

In code:

```
function convertData(input) {
  const output= [];

  const addEntry(e) {
    e.id = output.length;
    output.push(e);
  };

  input.forEach(e => {
    result = mapFn(e); // this is the same mapFn as above
    if (result.forEach) {
      result.forEach(addEntry);
    } else {
      addEntry(entry);
    }
  });

  return output;
}
```

Note that you can make this "less code" by using `.reduce()` but there's no efficiency gain in doing so.

Answer (score 0):

try this normal one

```js
var data = [{ cur: "GBT", val: [800, 450] }, { cur: "USD", val: 100 }, { cur: "EUR", val: 200 }, { cur: "GBT", val: [100, 250] }];

let r = [],counter = 1;;
data.map((d, i)=>{
let dummy  = {};
if(Array.isArray(d.val)){
 dummy['id'] = counter ++;
 dummy['cur'] = d.cur;
  dummy['val'] = d.val[0];
  r.push(dummy);
  dummy  = {};
   dummy['id'] = counter ++;
 dummy['cur'] = d.cur;
  dummy['val'] = d.val[1];
  r.push(dummy);
}else{
 dummy['id'] = counter ++;
 dummy['cur'] = d.cur;
  dummy['val'] = d.val;
  r.push(dummy);

}
  return 0;
});
console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplified alternative :

```js
var id = 0, arr = [ { cur: "GBT", val: [800, 450] },
                    { cur: "USD", val: 100 },
                    { cur: "EUR", val: 200 },
                    { cur: "GBT", val: [100, 250] } ]
            
var result = arr.flatMap(o => [o.val].flat().map(val => ({ ...o, val, id: id++ })))

console.log( result )
```